# Picasso cannot be applied to given types error Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm receiving this error and have no clue how to fix it: http://prntscr.com/lhb017
[image]

It used to work with `Picasso.with(getActivity())`, but with `Picasso.get` it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Picasso `get()` function is used this way : `Picasso.get().load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);` no argument needed for the function `get()`, so remove  `getActivity()` parameters from you `get()` function,

For further imformations : 
http://square.github.io/picasso/

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Depends of Picasso version, initialization is different.
If you are using last version from Maven Central

implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

you must remove getActivity() from initialization.

Answer (score 0):

It seems they have replaced with get() mehtod in the Singleton class of newest commit. In newest version of picasso get() method won't any parameter .So remove getActivity() method from the get() method.

```
 Picasso.get().load(url).into(imageView);

 implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```

You can also use with() which takes the context as a parameter if you are using the previous versions. It depends upon you which version you are using in your project .According to that you to maintain the method

In previous version of picasso library you can pass the context inside the with() method.

```
Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(imageView);
```

You can also refer their github project.

```
https://github.com/square/picasso/commit/e7e919232fe2b15772a7fcd9e15ead2304c66fae
```